# attr not worked in Chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, attr, rel

I've insert onclick to all  with below call function :
`onclick="javascript:loadcontent($(this).attr('rel'));`

this code working corectly in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome

How can I fix it ?

Comment: press F12 to access the chrome web inspector and let us know if there is an error

Comment: create an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I know F12 to access chrome web inspector but this function is not runing

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="" id="someSpecificLink">Try this instead</a>

$('#someSpecificLink').live('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  loadcontent($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

Comment: but I don't like use this code for all ".somelike" or all <a>
I need to use onclick

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the `javascript:`. It's unnecessary.
- Skip jQuery's `attr()` method. There's no benefit to it here.

`onclick="loadcontent(this.rel)";`

That said, these are both optimizations. There's no obvious reason why that code wouldn't work in most browsers. Check the browser's console for errors.

Comment: @Alex.k: Not surprising: as I mentioned, my suggestions were improvements but not fixes. It's impossible to diagnose the problem without more context.